# http hits: wordfence/v1/authenticate

Tags: wordfence

Recently, I’m getting hits like this:
/wp-json/wordfence/v1/authenticate?
(Followed by a string of numbers) about once an hour.

This is only happening on my AWS Lightsail (Bitnami) sites.

These appear to be coming from Wordfence, and I assume they have something to do with "wordfence central" where my sites are registered. I'm curious of these repeating hits (only on Lightsail) reflect some kind of configuration error or other problem.

I have asked wordfence, but it doesn't appear that I'm going to get an answer. Just wondered if anybody here has seen anything like this, or has any ideas.